# Add labels between two points in a line graph d3.js

Tags: javascript, d3.js

I'm trying to add labels to different sections of a line graph using d3.js. I'm working with a dataset that needs to be labelled by the end user by assigning labels to different section of the graph. My current under use case is to build something like the following:
[image]

While I am able to create the line graph, and can guess that the areas can be added to the graph as brushes, I'm unable to get started with regard it.

Comment: You don't need brushes, just add rectangles and labels at the positions specified by the user.

Comment: But, is there a way to make the text on the rectangles editable, and the rectangles themselves to appear only if the mouse is over it ?

Comment: Furthermore, I'd also been thinking along the lines of using a tooltip that is editable, but I'm not sure about how to start.

Comment: You could have an input field in a `foreignObject` element.

Comment: @LarsKotthoff Thanks a lot. I've been able to add the rect based on user clicks. However I'm having troubles with the overriding the onclick for the rectangles. Code + Question http://stackoverflow.com/questions/27497464/onclick-not-working-on-a-rect